# Importing Data from .CSV, Searching within Columns

Tags: python, csv, search

Python version: 3.7.4
Level of expertise: Beginner

I am trying to read data from a .CSV that contains four columns: Civic Number, Street Name, Neighbor and Data Type (either 'Existing' or 'New'). Existing records have the 'Neighbor' field populated with an address, new records are empty and require this information.

I am attempting to read the .csv and populate the new records with the address of their closest neighbor (Civic number + street name).

So far, I've been able to read the data by column. Now I am unsure how to proceed next. I want to first search for the new records and their associated addresses, then find the nearest neighbor and populate the 'Neighbor' field with that address. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

The data resembles:

```
'Civic Number', 'Street Name', 'Neighbor', 'Data Type'
'10', 'Main St', '11 Main St', 'Existing'
'40', 'Brook St', 'NONE', 'New'
Etc.
```

Here is all I have achieved so far:

```
import sys, csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('Test_Data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k,v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)

stName = columns['StreetName']
stNum = columns['CivicNum']
Neighbor = columns['Neighbor']
Type = columns['DataType']

print(stName)
print(stNum)
print(Neighbor)
print(Type)
```

Comment: how are you finding proximity without longitude and latitude? you either need a 3rd party API or another library although I don’t know any library that offers this functionality

Comment: Proximity would be determined by finding the existing record with a matching street name, and with the closest civic number. So I would like to get rows with the same street, calculate absolute values and then get min() to find the nearest address.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary file where you will store updated information after processing. Open the original(use for read purpose) and temporary(use for write purpose) files. The rows where Data Type field is set to New in the original, update the Neighbour field to the nearest value(I have added 1 to it) and create a new row to be written in the temporary.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
import csv

filename = 'file.csv'
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)

fields = ['Civic Number', 'Street Name', 'Neighbor', 'Data Type']

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile, tempfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=fields)

    for row in reader:
        if row['Data Type'] == 'New':
            row['Neighbor'] = str(int(row['Civic Number']) + 1) + ' ' + row['Street Name']
        row = {'Civic Number': row['Civic Number'], 'Street Name': row['Street Name'], 'Neighbor': row['Neighbor'], 'Data Type': 'Existing'}
        writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful actually.

Comment: @gisele_gis if this helped you, I will appreciate if you can approve this answer